# Doctrine and ManyToOne entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entities, country and Province, and I have set up a many-to-one relation in the Province entity:

Entity/Province

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Country
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Country")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ubicacionpaisid", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
private $ubicacionpaisid;
```

Here I get all results using the Province entity:

```
 $cb = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getEntityManager()
        ->getRepository(Province::class)
        ->createQueryBuilder('a');
```

However, if I run:

```
 var_dump($cb->getQuery()->getDQL());
```

it returns:

```
string(41) "SELECT a FROM AppBundle\Entity\Province a"
```

What I expected to see was a query that joins the Country entity, into the Province entity in the SQL.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Off topic but instead of using var_dump, just use dump.  Be surprised at how clean the output looks.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize 2 people gave answers that just say to use `EAGER` loading of the association.  But I can't recommend that.  This makes so many assumptions about your project and how you'd always want to join that association no matter what, and can even [cause issues](http://jayroman.com/blog/be-careful-with-doctrine-magic-and-symfony2) with forms and creating unexpected behavior.

Plus, the user already is showing that they're using a custom QueryBuilder call to grab the data, so why not explicitly use the join?

For example:

```
$cb = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository(Province::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('p, c')
    ->join('p.ubicacionpaisid', 'c')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

or better yet, from with a ProvinceRepository:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('p, c')
    ->join('p.ubicacionpaisid', 'c')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

Comment: this works, but i have to use "WITH" and " a.ubicacionpaisid = p.id" in join. definitely, doctrine is not recognizing the relation between entities. But after update schema, in php myadmin the foreign key appears ... fetch EAGER is not working for me.

Comment: I wonder if it without the `WITH` now that the foreign key appears.  Hmm.  Either way glad it's working.

Comment: I agree that this is the better answer if he was actually asking for the best way to build his queries. But the question was why the SQL wasn't showing the join, so IMHO your answer is WRONG.

Comment: I also concur that EAGER should not be used all the time, as the consequences can have a huge impact on performance, but for debugging purposes i think it is ok.

Comment: Saying my answer is wrong is a stretch. He provided an ORM definition *and* a query and asked what was missing.  He was either missing the `JOIN` or the `EAGER` fetching.  You provided an answer for what was missing in the Entity definition, and I provided an answer for what was missing in the query.  Rather than one of our answers being 'wrong', I'd consider them to both be correct. :)

Answer (score 2):

This might be because Doctrine has 2 types of joins.
A normal join and a fetch join. In the fetch join, Doctrine will preform 2 different queries and then just hydrate the result of the second back into the result/data of the first.

It's sometimes also referred to as a lazy join. Lazy joins are the default behavior.
You can change this behavior by altering your relation with [`fetch="EAGER"`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetomany)

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Country
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Country", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ubicacionpaisid", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

As DarkMukke said...

Did you try to fetch the data?

Adding in your relation fetch="EAGER"

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Country
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Country", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ubicacionpaisid", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
private $ubicacionpaisid;
```

This should fetch and load the associated entity as well.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone

Comment: GJ you literally said what i said

Comment: true, it wasn't there when I started writing it though. I give you the credit ;)